# How to find a member role in a specific server

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have these two lines of code which checks if the message author have a specific role into the main server of the bot :

```js
const main = client.guilds.cache.get(698725823464734852);

// Blacklist Checker :
if (message.author.main.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "BlackListed.")) message.reply("you are blacklisted...")
```

I have tried to connect the functions at `message.author.main.roles.cache.find`  however, it didn't work.

Comment: The guild id should be a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with the code you have provided us with;
Firstly the guild ID must be a string and secondly `message.author.main` will give you an error.
Please see the working code I have provided below.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js'); //Define discord
const client = new Discord.Client(); //Define client

client.on('message', message => {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('698725823464734852'); // Define guild (guild ID must be a string)
    const member = guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id); //Find the message author in the guild
    if (!member) return console.log('Member is not blacklisted'); //If the member is notin the guild
    if (member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name.toLowerCase() === 'blacklisted')) return message.reply('Unfortunately, you have been blacklisted.'); //Let the user know they have been blacklisted.
});
```

Comment: thank you vm, and also thanks for the explaining, have a nice day/night.